# Why rails 4 tests does not reset db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I'm using Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.7.
I'm also using minitest ( ActionController::TestCase ) and these gems

```
gem 'capybara', '~>2.7.1'
gem 'poltergeist', '~>1.9.0'
gem 'minitest-rails-capybara', '~>2.1.2'
```

I was under the impression that everytime 'rake test' is called, the database is dropped and created with schema.rb (as it happens in all my other projects)

But with this project it doesn't do this (If i manually change something on the test db, it stay that way between test)

Is this normal? What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Rails (or RSpec or Minitest) doesn't drop the database before running tests.

Perhaps you used a gem like [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) in the other projects before?

Comment: The problem was that there were no migrations, and in that case it tries to update the database based on the schema.

You can avoid it setting  'config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false'